# problems defining overlapping @Path values for Jersey JAX RS

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I have two resource classes

```
Pc.java - @Path("/pc")
Tag.java - @Path("/{entity:(pc|networks)?}/{id}/tags")
```

So the second resource handles a branch of '/pc' or '/networks' urls that end with '/tags'.

But the problem is none of my methods in Tag.java are getting called.  I think this is because Pc.java is configured to handle /pc, so all calls get redirected to that resource and Tag.java doesn't get called, so i get a 404 error.

1. I can handle this by changing /tag to be the parent path and having (pc/networks) under it, but I dont want to do that because it doesnt suit the style of the rest of the urls in our project.
2. I can have two sets of methods - one set under Pc.java which handles '/pc' and another set under Network.java which handles '/networks', but this seems like duplicating code...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps at least part of Tag should be a [sub-resource](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2542) of Pc?

Comment: you mean have some '/pc.../tags' sub-resources in Pc.java and the rest in Tag.java...sorry didn't get you.

Comment: missed the link in your answer.  looks like i'll get my answer if i read it fully.  Thanks!

Comment: yes, sub-resource locators is the way to go!  So I define a separate resource that handles '/tags' - Tag.java...and in each of Pc.java and Network.java i just have one sub-resource for '/tags' which returns an instance of Tag...thanks for this link!  I've accepted your answer.